# Understanding of basic properties of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for my Linear Algebra exam, and this is one of the questions in a previous exam. Sadly I'm not quite sure I get it.

**The question goes:**

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $R$−vector space
Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$, and $T,S \in\mbox{End}(V)$. Decide if the statements are true or false for any choice of $U, W, T$, and $S$.

1. $\dim(U + W) = \max\{\dim(U),\dim(W)\}$
2. $\dim(U + W) ≥ \min\{\dim(U),\dim(W)\}$
3. $\dim(U\oplus W) =\dim(U) + \dim(W)$
4. $\dim(U \cap W) = \min\{\dim(U), \dim(W)\}$
5. $\{0\}\subseteq U\cap W$
6. $U \cup W$ is a subspace of $V$
7. Let $\{v_1, . . . , v_n\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $V$.
   Then $\dim(V) ≥ n$.
8. $\dim(\ker(T)) + \dim(\mbox{im}(T)) = \dim(V )$
9. There exists $F\in\mbox{Hom}(R^2 , R^3)$ such that $F$ is injective.
10. $\mbox{im}(ST) = \mbox{im}(S)$

Course vs. Book

$\mbox{Hom}(V, W) | L(V, W)$

$\mbox{End}(V ) | L(V )$

$\ker |\mbox{null}$

$\mbox{im}| \mbox{range}$

**My thoughts:**

1. So I guess this is false, cause $dim(U+W)$ are suppose to be equal OR bigger
   than $\max\{\dim(U), dim(W)\}$, but theoretically I don't understand why?
2. Must be True, cause the absolute minimum of the two dimensions, will always be smaller than the dimension of their addition?
3. This I've been told is True, because $dim(U \oplus W) = dim(U) + dim(W)-dim(U\cap W)$ but why is it that the intersection is $0$?
4. This again, I've been told that the intersection is $0$ and the minimum is $1$, but I'm not sure why?
5. Well if the intersection is zero, then, of course, {$0$} must be in the intersection.
6. Must be false, cause units are not subspaces.
7. True. Of course, there could not be a vector bigger than the dimension, but the dimension does contain smaller vectors. (This is not good math language I know, just my thought to understand it.)
8. This we know is true from the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps ("Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler)
9. I do believe this is true, but can't explain it?
10. I don't know, but I don't get how the range of two subspaces could be the same as one of them? Maybe if T is also a subspace of S? Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done well. But to get full marks in an exam you need to give a counterexample to prove a statement false or a short proof (or sometimes example) to prove a statement true.

(1) Correct. It is false. Counterexample: $U$ = all multiples of $\mathbf{u}$ and $V$ = all multiples of $\mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{u,v}$ are linearly independent. Then dim($U$)=dim($V$)=1 but dim($U+V$)=2.

(2) Correct. True because $U\subseteq U+V$.

(3) Correct. True. By definition $U\oplus V$ has $U\cap V=0$.

(4) Correct. False. Take the same $U,V$ as in (1) above. The dim($U$)=dim($V$)=1 but dim($U\cap V$)=0.

(5) Correct. True. The zero vector belongs to any subspace, so it must belong to $U\cap V$.

(6) Correct. False. Take $U,V$ as in (1) above. Then $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\notin U\cup V$, but $\mathbf{u,v}\in U\cup V$. So $U\cup V$ is not closed under vector addition.

(7) Correct. True. The dimension is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors.

(8) Correct. True. The rank-nullity theorem.

(9) Correct. True. Example: define $F(x,y)=(x,y,0)$. [Check this is a homomorphism and injective].

(10). False. I do not know whether you take $ST$ to mean first $S$, then $T$ or vice versa (both conventions are used). But either way take $S$ to be the identity map and $T$ the null map. Then the image of $S$ is $V$, but the image of $ST$ is 0.

------- Added later -------

re (9) and your comment below. Yes. Injective means one-one, or as you say, $Tu=Tv$ implies $u=v$. That is clearly true for the example given above.

re (9) and your second comment below. To check that $T$ is a homomorphism we just need it to be a linear map, ie $T(\lambda u+\mu v)=\lambda Tu+\mu Tv$ for all vectors $u,v$ and scalars $\lambda,\mu$. In the case of the example above that is obviously true.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got most of them now!

But I'm stil a little insecure about number (9), can't seem to find the theory in my book. 

I have a Definition that says:
A function $T:V ->W$ is called injective if $Tu=Tv$ implies $u=v$

Comment: But how do I tjek if it is homomorphism, I remember my teacher talking about this, but can't find it in the book or my notes, so not sure

Comment: Thank you so much, now I get it!